# How can I add a +NAME: to an org-mode table created through emacs-lisp?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have the following code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table
  (append '(("a" "b" "c" "d")
        hline
        (1 2 3 4)
        (5 6 7 8)))
#+END_SRC
```

When I run this source block, that gives me the expected result

```
#+RESULTS:
| a | b | c | d |
|---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

What I want is to add a `#+NAME`: to the table so that I can reference it later, like this:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+NAME: my-table
| a | b | c | d |
|---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

I have seen the example in the org mode manual in Section 15.6 that uses postprocessing, but that example uses sh for the processor and for various reasons I want to stick to emacs-lisp. I have tried various things but I can't get the postprocessing to work. The main problem seems to be that the postprocessing block has to be `:results output`, not `:results value`, but it is passed the table as a Lisp object, which I would have to format again as a string to prepend the `#+NAME:` string.

How can I get a #+NAME: added to my table using only emacs lisp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual trick is to add the `#+NAME:` *before* the results, but for that to work well, you should also name the code block (which in turn will have the effect of labeling the results block, so babel can find it and replace it, rather than producing more results blocks):

```org
#+NAME: my-table-producer
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value table
  (append '(("a" "b" "c" "d")
        hline
        (1 2 3 4)
        (5 6 7 8)))
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: my-table
#+RESULTS: my-table-producer
| a | b | c | d |
|---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |


#+begin_src python :var tbl=my-table :results output
print(tbl)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

As you can see, the `#+NAME:` before the `#+RESULTS:` (with *nothing* in between) is effective: the python code block was able to find the table and assign it to `tbl`.

Comment: OMG, I never thought I could add a #+NAME: BEFORE the result block. Thanks, that solves my problem completely.

Comment: However, if you don't name the code block and put the table name before the *named* `#+RESULTS:` block, you will be cursing me for ever :-) Or at least every time you evaluate the code block. So make sure to do that as well.

Comment: Yeah, I heeded your advice and it works like a charm in my production code. Also, I think I've already exceeded my curse quota for today.

Comment: I'm just going through the manual again and I can't find the option to name result blocks anywhere. Is that documented and I've just missed it?

Comment: See the first code block in my answer. It is done the same way as with a table: add `#+NAME: foo` above the code block. You can find the description for that particular use in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Structure-of-Code-Blocks), but `#+NAME` is one of the so-called `affiliated keywords`, i.e. keywords that you can attach to other things. You can find a description in the `Affiliated Keywords` subsection of the [Keywords](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Keywords) section in the [Syntax](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html) document on Worg.

Comment: BTW, you don't name result blocks: the `#+RESULTS` block is labeled with the name of the source block. What that does is it makes sure that if you evaluate the code block again, you will not generate yet another `#+RESULTS` block (which *would* happen if you left the source block unnamed and added the `#+NAME` for the table before the `#+RESULT` keyword). The `#+NAME` keyword before the results block does *NOT* name the results block: it "flows through" the `#+RESULTS` keyword to name the thing *after* it.